# CentOS Ignoring Timezone and showing UTC

Tags: linux, centos

I've set my server's timezone to Central:

```
/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central
```

After rebooting, when I run the date command, the time is still listed in UTC.

```
[root@dev etc]# date
Sat Oct  5 16:14:28 UTC 2013
```

How can I get it to display in the local timezone?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `strace -v date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if there is something wrong with this file: /etc/localtime

Using for example:

```
zdump -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central or zdump -v /etc/localtime
```

In my case the information for this year looks like this:

```
/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central  Sun Mar 10 07:59:59 2013 UTC = Sun Mar 10 01:59:59 2013 CST isdst=0 gmtoff=-21600
/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central  Sun Mar 10 08:00:00 2013 UTC = Sun Mar 10 03:00:00 2013 CDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-18000
/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central  Sun Nov  3 06:59:59 2013 UTC = Sun Nov  3 01:59:59 2013 CDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-18000
/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central  Sun Nov  3 07:00:00 2013 UTC = Sun Nov  3 01:00:00 2013 CST isdst=0 gmtoff=-21600
```

Comment: I think you found the problem.  Here is the output of zdump -v /etc/localtime: `/etc/localtime  -9223372036854775808 = NULL
/etc/localtime  -9223372036854689408 = NULL
/etc/localtime  9223372036854689407 = NULL
/etc/localtime  9223372036854775807 = NULL`

Comment: updating tzdata via yum solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Timekeeping tips for your CentOS system.

- Set the timezone offset with something like: `ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime`
- Check the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/clock` - Mine only contains `ZONE="America/Chicago"`
- Turn on `ntp`. There's no excuse *not* to have it running.
- If this is a physical system, you may want to set your hardware clock in your bios or set it from your OS with `hwclock -w`

These changes take effect immediately, such that your date command should output:

```
# date
Sat Oct  5 11:38:49 CDT 2013
```

Comment: I tried all of this, yet the date is still output in UTC.  I noticed in my /etc/sysconfig/clock file, there is a variable called UTC set to true.  I tried setting that to false (without rebooting) but it didn't change anything.  What does your entire clock file look like?

Comment: That's all that's in my clock file.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure that the environment variable `TZ` is unset, as it overrides what is configured by `/etc/localtime`.

Even an innocent `export TZ=` makes date (and other utilities) default to outputting UTC.

Check `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, your Desktop Environment configuration and other commonly sourced configuration files for instances of setting and exporting TZ and remove them.

Edit:

Also check that your `/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central` is a valid existing file:

```
$ file -L /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central
/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central: timezone data, version 2, 6 gmt time flags, 6 std time flags, no leap seconds, 235 transition times, 6 abbreviation chars
```

Comment: I checked all of these locations and TZ is not set anywhere.  I ran echo $TZ from the command line and got a blank response:

Comment: A blank response doesn't help you in this case, since even a TZ variable set to an empty string makes date report back in UTC, as pointed out in my answer.

Instead, check the output of `env` or `set` for the occurrence of TZ.

Also check that your `/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central` is a valid existing file.

Comment: My zone file appears valid: file -L /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central
/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central: timezone data.  I also ran printenv and the TZ variable is not set.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue and updating tzdata fixed it for me:

```
yum update tzdata
```